# Print multiple PDF[double sided] using batch

Tags: pdf, batch, batch-file, printing

I am trying to print 1000 `.pdf` file's with 2 pages each.
I've got this:

```
@echo off
set filelocation="F:\TP\T\1"
set filetype="*.pdf"
set printer="\\gh0cd33\HP LaserJet 400 M401 PCL 6"
cd %filelocation%
for %%f in (%filetype%) do AcroRd32.exe /t %%f %printer% & timeout 5 >nul
```

The problem with it is that it prints one .pdf page per paper sheet [*from 1 .pdf with 2 pages I get 2 paper sheets instead of 1*], altrough the printers default settings  are "print on both sides".
Im running this from a Win10.
Last year Ive done this:

```
Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer
DWORD -> MultipleInvokePromptMinimum -> 16
```

to print more then 15 files , but now all it does is to print the file Ive right clickt even trough tere ware 20 files selected.

Comment: Can you clarify: you say "prints only one page {although set for duplex}." Do you mean it prints 2 single-sided pages, or do you mean that it is only printing page 1.

Comment: Lets say I use this batch file to print only 1 .pdf with 2 pages, I want the output to be one paper file printed on both sides(front and back) [double sided]

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the `MultipleInvokePromptMinimum`,
If you set it to `16` the Print, Edit and Open options will no longer hide when selecting more then `15` files, **BUT** it will only Print/Edit/Oppen `16` files, if more are selected it will take action only on the file you right click.

**NOTE:**
This does not answer the question , it only explains why your last metod did not work( I do not have enought Rep to add it as a comment).

**Side NOTE:**
I strongly sugest you to wait for a proper answer to your question rather then making the limit 2000 files, even if you have a realy good workstation it is bound to break in the middle of printing .